# Create bootable usb from recovery partition in linux

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, boot, usb

I want to create a bootable USB from the recovery partition of my Lenovo laptop from Linux. I can mount the ntfs recovery partition in linux and see that it contains the Windows Recovery Environment files (`Winre.vim` etc). How do I make a bootable usb out of it?

I've tried copying the partition to the usb using dd:

```
dd if=/dev/sda4 of=/dev/sdb
```

But it won't boot; "Disk read error". I've tried creating an ntfs partition on the usb, then copying the partition with ntfsclone:

```
ntfsclone /dev/sda4 -O /dev/sdb1
```

But it just gives a flashing cursor when booting from the usb. I've also tried setting the bootable flag on the partition but it just gives "Disk read error" again.

What's the right way to create a bootable usb from the ntfs recovery partition?